# Object initialization using InterfaceType

Tags: java

Iam new to java programming language.I was programming in c# for last two years.When i went through the java program i find a code as follows.

```
ArgumentParser parser = ArgumentParsers.newArgumentParser("text");
```

where ArgumentParser  is an InterfaceType and ArgumentParsers is a class.But i couldn't find any implementation for ArgumentParser  in ArgumentParsers.How can we create an object of an interfacetype by initilizing the object with a class which doesnot implement that interface.
I don't know it is possible in c#.Please help me explain this

Thanks

Comment: The method `ArgumentParsers.newArgumentParser` returns an instance of a class that implements interface `ArgumentParser`. Look at the implementation the method `ArgumentParsers.newArgumentParser` if you want to know what exactly it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're just calling a static method in the `ArgumentParsers` class. You should look at the implementation of `ArgumentParsers.newArgumentParser` to see which implementation of `ArgumentParser` is used.

This isn't peculiar to Java, either. For example, methods like [`File.OpenRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openread.aspx) and [`XmlReader.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.create.aspx) are both declared with return types which are abstract classes - the same thing would work with interfaces.

For example, if you wanted to translate the Java code to C#, this would be valid:

```
public interface IArgumentParser
{
    Configuration Parse(string[] arguments);
}

public static class ArgumentParsers
{
    public static IArgumentParser(string file)
    {
        return new FileArgumentParser(file);
    }
}

internal class FileArgumentParser : IArgumentParser
{
    private readonly string file;

    internal FileArgumentParser(string file)
    {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public Configuration Parse(string[] arguments)
    {
        // Presumably use the file somewhere...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ArgumentParsers` is just a factory and `newArgumentParser(String)` is a static method which returns an instance of a Class that implements `ArgumentParser` probably depending what String-parameter you pass.

[Factory-Method-Pattern (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)